# Is there a Kotlin-Multiplatform feature or pattern that can help to implement a common abstraction for, say, the Closeable interface?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-native, kotlin-multiplatform

The Closeable interface in Java provides a convenient abstraction that facilitates the management of resources that can be closed. In the context of multi-platform kotlin, is there a pattern, practice or feature that can help breach the gap between a shared/multi-platform Closeable interface and the actual Java Closeable interface knowing that these are necessarily two different types?

The effects of not being able to close the type difference and/or having a standard-lib closeable are the proliferation of Closeable interfaces that can't be combined across libraries even though they are fundamentally the same thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is already done for you in kotlinx-io library from the Kotlin team.

https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx-io

For `Closeable` you should use that library directly, no need to create your own.

---

But if you want to create your own similar cross-platform abstraction, this acts as a nice sample. Here is what it is doing underneath the covers...

The **common implementation** which actually does the logic of closing and just expects each platform to have the interface available: [(source)](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx-io/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/kotlinx/io/core/Closeable.kt)

```
expect interface Closeable {
    fun close()
}

inline fun <C : Closeable, R> C.use(block: (C) -> R): R {
    try {
        val result = block(this)
        close()
        return result
    } catch (first: Throwable) {
        try {
            close()
        } catch (second: Throwable) {
            first.addSuppressedInternal(second)
        }
        throw first
    }
}

@PublishedApi
internal expect fun Throwable.addSuppressedInternal(other: Throwable)
```

The **JVM version** is just a simple type alias that matches the expected interface meaning that it is compatible with existing code, and implementation of suppressing the inner exception. [(source)](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx-io/blob/master/kotlinx-io-jvm/src/main/kotlin/kotlinx/io/core/CloseableJVM.kt)

```
actual typealias Closeable = java.io.Closeable

@PublishedApi
internal actual fun Throwable.addSuppressedInternal(other: Throwable) {
    AddSuppressedMethod?.invoke(this, other)
}

private val AddSuppressedMethod: Method? by lazy {
    try {
        Throwable::class.java.getMethod("addSuppressed", Throwable::class.java)
    } catch (t: Throwable) {
        null
    }
}
```

And the **JS version** is a new interface: [(source)](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx-io/blob/master/kotlinx-io-js/src/main/kotlin/kotlinx/io/core/CloseableJS.kt)

```
actual interface Closeable {
    actual fun close()
}

@PublishedApi
internal actual fun Throwable.addSuppressedInternal(other: Throwable) {
}
```

For [native it is similar to JS](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx-io/blob/master/kotlinx-io-native/src/main/kotlin/kotlinx/io/core/CloseableNative.kt), and so on for each platform...

Comment: Thank you this is the common denominator I was looking for. Is there an analogous thing for the rx Observable interface to bridge reactive streams across platforms? This would allow declaring a multi-platform Observable interface that can be bound to the corresponding platform implementation (e.g. rxjava, rxswift, etc).

Comment: That is more complex, but you could do the same, although you can't abstract Swift under Kotlin because the interoperability is the other way around.  You would need a custom implementation in kotlin-native to use from Swift which would be a lot of work.  Many people are using coroutines instead of rxwhatever these days anyways.

Comment: I was about to ask for some rationale to `expect` different `actual` implementation of interfaces and your answer just brought up a strong example.